# Want to create a procedure which will accept integer input, compare with the count of table and on true create backup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, procedure

Problem Statement- Want to create a procedure which will accept integer input.

- Compare this integer input with the ROW COUNT of the table A if matched then create copy of the table A
  -if not matched take the count difference and email to required list of email.

Comment: what is a "count of the table". what have you tried so far?

Comment: backup the table means do you want create new table with that data or update the not existed data in one table ?

Comment: Have you tried something? If so, why didn't it work? If not, why not?

Comment: Is it an assignment ? show us some efforts.

Comment: @amit malviya Hi Did you get the code

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DealCount int  
SET @DealCount =1234

IF @DealCount = (SELECT count(*) from A) 
    THEN ( INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE from A)

ELSE  
    SELECT count(*)- @DealCount from A
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you

```
DECLARE @CheckCount      INT=15, --Input your data count
        @CheckTableCount INT, 
        @TableWithDate   DATE =Getdate(), 
        @Sql             NVARCHAR(max), 
        @myRecipientList VARCHAR(max), 
        @DiffTableCount  INT 

IF EXISTS(SELECT Count(1) 
          FROM   employees) 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT @CheckTableCount = Count(1) 
      FROM   employees 

      IF ( @CheckTableCount = @CheckCount ) 
        BEGIN 
            SET @Sql=N' SELECT * INTO TableName_' 
                     + Replace(Cast(@TableWithDate AS VARCHAR(10)), '-', '') 
                     + ' FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE 1=1' 

            PRINT @Sql 

            EXECUTE(@Sql) 
        END 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @CheckTableCount = Count(1) 
            FROM   employees 

            SELECT @DiffTableCount = @CheckTableCount - @CheckCount 

            SET @myRecipientList = ( Stuff((SELECT ';' + emailaddress 
                                            FROM   table 
                                            FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '') ) 

            EXEC msdb.dbo.Sp_send_dbmail 
              @profile_name = 'DBMail', 
              @recipients = @myRecipientList, 
              @subject = 'There is difference in table count', 
              @attach_query_result_as_file = 1; 
        END 
  END
```